# ASP.NET Core Razor PageModel ModelState Invalid because of new Navigation Property with Id==0

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to update an entity that may have an optional NavigationProperty from an html form.

```
public class ProcessDataGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ReadDataGroupStrategy ReadDataGroupStrategy { get; set; }
    public ReadBlockDefinition ReadBlockDefinition { get; set; }
    public int? ReadBlockDefinitionId { get; set; }
}

public class ReadBlockDefinition
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public int Offset { get; set; }
}
```

If `ReadBlockDefinition` already exists and has an `Id > 0`, this works. I attach the entity to my `DbContext` and it will by updated.
But it is possible that in the html form the `ReadDataGroupStrategy` is changed and then a new `ReadBlockDefinition` is created, that by default of course has an `Id` of 0. 
In this case `ModelState.IsValid` will return false und investigation during debugging discovers that is it complaining about the `ReadBlockDefinition.Id` field, so it seems it won't accept 0 there.
I cannot skip the Id field from the `ReadBlockDefinition` ViewModel because it is essential for updates.

My workaround at the moment is

```
if(ProcessDataGroup?.ReadBlockDefinition?.Id == 0)
    ModelState.Remove("ProcessDataGroup.ReadBlockDefinition.Id");
```

before evaluating `ModelState.IsValid` but this seems a rather strange solution to me. I'm generally not sure why validation fails in the first place. As I understood so far, validation isn't related to EF Core or whatever underlying technology and 0 should be a perfectly valid integer.

Any ideas how to overcome this? Or is the `ModelState.Remove(...)` approach the intended one?

Comment: What is the version of your project ? And what's the logic between your page and the PageModel ? Could you share more details about the razor pages and the handler ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered setting the data annotations for Id?

```
public class ReadBlockDefinition
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public int Offset { get; set; }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations